# How to extract matching strings from array and create new array

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I need to extract strings that contain the word 'DREAMS' from 'STYLE.' and create a new array with it.

MongoDB Documents:

```
[
  {
    name: "STYLE",
    params: ['DREAMS-FEEDING', 'DREAMS-PARI', 'SOFT']
  }, 
  {
    name: "BRAND",
    params: ['DREAMS', 'FEATHERLINE']
  }
]
```

The result should be:

```
['DREAMS-FEEDING', 'DREAMS-PARI']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply the `$regex` operator to the `params` array. In the projection, with `$filter` and `$regexMatch` operators to filter the element(s) in the array.

```
db.collection.find({
  name: "STYLE",
  params: {
    $regex: "DREAMS"
  }
},
{
  name: 1,
  params: {
    $filter: {
      input: "$params",
      cond: {
        $regexMatch: {
          input: "$$this",
          regex: "DREAMS"
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9f8Sxkl1OxI)

Comment: Depends on your MongoDB driver and language syntax, if you get one item, to get the `params` array: `result[0].params`